# A pre-compiled binary from ubuntu gets seg fault on alpine due to duplocale()

Tags: c, linker, segmentation-fault, alpine-linux

I have code I compiled on my `Ubuntu 22.04`:

```c
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        printf("1\n");
        locale_t oldlocale = uselocale(NULL);
        printf("2\n");
        locale_t duploc = duplocale(oldlocale);
        printf("3\n");
        return 0;
}
```

Running it on the same `Ubuntu` works:

```bash
$ gcc -g c.c && ./a.out 
1
2
3
```

But after copying it into an `alpine container`, I get a seg fault:

```bash
# ./a.out 
1
2
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

As you can see, it happens due to the function `duplocale()`.
I have installed on that `alpine container` couple of stuff, such as `libc6-compat`.
When compiling the same piece of code on `alpine` and then running it, it works. But this isn't the case and I cannot use that approach. I need to be able to compile on `Ubuntu`.  The original issue is having `libjson-c` which uses this `duplocale()` and gets seg fault.  Even when dynamically linking with `-ljson-c` and then using `alpine`'s `json-c` I still get this seg fault.

Is there a way to work around it?
Thanks

---

Update: backtrace - there's not much of it.

- Through `alpine`:

```
process 340 is executing new program: /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1
1
2

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7f46aa7 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7f46aa7 in ?? ()
#1  0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#2  0x00007ffff7f521cd in ?? ()
#3  0xffffffffffffffff in ?? ()
#4  0x00007ffff7fc1600 in __libc_start_init () at ldso/dynlink.c:1621
#5  0x00007ffff7f786d1 in libc_start_main_stage2 (main=0x7ffff7f52189, argc=-1, argv=0x7fffffffebb0)
    at src/env/__libc_start_main.c:95
#6  0x00007ffff7f520c5 in ?? ()
#7  0x00007fffffffebf8 in ?? ()
#8  0x00007ffff7f520a0 in ?? ()
#9  0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#10 0x00007fffffffee50 in ?? ()
#11 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

- Taking the core back to `Ubuntu` and checking it there:

```
Core was generated by `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --argv0 ./a.out --preload /lib/libgcompat.so.0  -- /dm/res'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f1c76999aa7 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f1c76999aa7 in ?? ()
#1  0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#2  0x00007f1c769a51cd in ?? ()
#3  0xffffffffffffffff in ?? ()
#4  0x00007f1c76a0e600 in ?? ()
#5  0x00007ffc8621ad98 in ?? ()
#6  0x00007f1c769c56d1 in ?? ()
#7  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Note, the file is `with debug_info, not stripped`.

---

I just found out this, maybe it's related https://github.com/json-c/json-c/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L178C11-L178C24:

> ```bash
> # uClibc *intentionally* crashes in duplocale(), at least as of:
> # https://github.com/ffainelli/uClibc/blob/266bdc1/libc/misc/locale/locale.c#L1322
> # So, if it looks like we're compiling for a system like that just disable
> # locale handling entirely.
> ```

Comment: Can you share the backtrace of the crash?

Comment: @kiner_shah, added. Not sure how I can make it more readable.

Comment: `uselocale()` can return `NULL`, which would lead to a segfault on `duplocale()`. Perhaps you should add some error handling.

Comment: @hudac, seems symbols are stripped-off. Can you build with symbols and try once, if it crashes, share its backtrace.

Comment: @Ctx, the return value is `0xffffffffffffffff`, not `NULL`.

Comment: @kiner_shah, as I wrote above, the file is `with debug_info, not stripped`. The thing is, inside `alpine` it uses `musl` instead of `libc`, so I guess it makes things complicated.

Comment: I just found out this, maybe it's related https://github.com/json-c/json-c/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L178C11-L178C24

Comment: The uClibc thing is probably unrelated.

Comment: If Alpine is using a different C library implementation than your Ubuntu compile box, then no, you cannot assume that binaries built for the compile box will work correctly in the Alpine container.  You need to build *for* Alpine (or at least for musl), which is an exercise in cross-compilation.  That will require an appropriate cross-toolchain and suitable cross versions of all required libraries.

Comment: Alternatively, even though you say you can't build directly in the target environment, it might be worth your while to set up a separate Alpine environment in which to perform your builds.  That could avoid the need for cross-compilation.

Comment: Alternatively, you could try building with the `musl-gcc` wrapper from the `musl-tools` package.

Comment: @IanAbbott, right. The thing is, my build process is quite complicated and involve lots of stuff. So for my current build system I cannot use it easily.